# How to get a post by id and all posts at the same time?Laravel

Tags: laravel

My Controller:

```
public function post($code, $id){

      $specpost = Post::where('id', $id)->get();

      return view('post', compact('specpost'));
    }
```

This way I get a specific post. Also on the same page, I randomly want to recommend other posts to the user, how can I get them? Write another variable with the `all` query(`$all = Post::all();`)? It seems to me not very correct, are there other methods?

Comment: Exactly, a mistake)

Comment: `Post::find($id)` or `Post::findOrFail($id)` will make life easier  `:)`

Comment: Thanks more, I'll try!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use union or create anthor pramter
like

```
  $specpost = Post::where('id', $id)->get();
  $TenPosts = Post::inRandomOrder()->take(10)->get()

  return view('post', compact('specpost','TenPosts'));
```

Comment: maybe add a `where('id', '<>', $id)` to the random one so it can't grab the one they already grabbed? just in case  :)

Comment: I just heard that 2 fetch from one controller overloads it, will this affect performance?

Comment: i just 2 db query